# Create an array inside javascript class to accommodate multiple objects

Tags: javascript, class

I am trying to create an array collection of objects inside a JavaScript class.

```
class Person {
  object = {};
  employees = new Array();

  constructor() {}

  addPerson(name, age) {
    this.object.name = name;
    this.object.age = age;
    this.employees.push(this.object);
  }

  getGroupInfo() {
    return this.employees;
  }
}

let p1 = new Person();
p1.addPerson("Johnny", 40);
p1.addPerson("Mark", 55);
console.log(p1.getGroupInfo());
```

The output seems to override with the second input that I am providing.

```
[ 
  { name: 'Mark', age: 55 }, 
  { name: 'Mark', age: 55 } 
]
```

I am certainly failing to understand the basic javascript way of class creation :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second call to `addPerson` is using a **reference** of the first `this.object` and changing the values. You can directly add new objects to the `employees` array as follows:

```js
class Person {
  employees = new Array();
  constructor() {}

  addPerson(name, age) {
    this.employees.push({name, age});
  }

  getGroupInfo() {
    return this.employees;
  }
}

let p1 = new Person();
p1.addPerson("Johnny", 40);
p1.addPerson("Mark", 55);
console.log(p1.getGroupInfo());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p1.addPerson("Johnny", 40);
p1.addPerson("Mark", 55);
```

Both these statements update and work on the same object : `this.object` which is a property of the `p1` instance. The array becomes something like
`[x,x]`.

Answer (score 0):

`this.object` inside Person is same for both. So its value getting overridden

```js
class Person {
  name;
  age;

  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}

employees = new Array();
let p1 = new Person("Johnny", 40);
let p2 = new Person("Mark", 55);
employees.push(p1);
employees.push(p2);
console.log(employees);
```

Comment: Thanks! but I wanted to specifically create a collection inside the same object.

Answer (score 0):

I have accepted the first answer  which is correct. One other way I could have implemented it :

```
class Person {
  employees = new Array();

  constructor() {}

  addPerson(name, age) {
    let object = {};
    object.name = name;
    object.age = age;
    this.employees.push(object);
  }

  getGroupInfo() {
    return this.employees;
  }

 }
}
```